# Question about Buttons and INPUT_PULLUP

Tags: button

I am ok as a developer but have very little experience if it comes to electronics/hardware. I am always too cautious and have the fear that I could wreck something with the wrong wiring. This question may sound silly to you, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. It's probably very easy to answer.

I'd like to integrate a Push Button into my Arduino Uno Setup. The only other connections are 3 wires leading to an WS2811b Strip, standard setup. From what I have found out online, I should basically connect Digital Pin 2 (or any other) to one side/connector of the Button and GND to the other side, no Resistor, and then set the Pin Mode to INPUT_PULLUP:

```
pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

This makes sense. But all tutorials I'v seen use these small black Push Buttons looking like the Reset Switch. I needed something bigger, so I bought these:
https://de.aliexpress.com/item/4001095221773.html

Now the question: Should I connect these Buttons to my Arduino in the same way? Or could it be that there is some difference from one type of Push Button to the other that I have not thought about (that could probably ruin things)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello fellow programmer. I suggest you to google word Tinkercad. :) You are welcome.

Comment: Aha. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just connect them in the same way.

It doesn't matter what type of button you use. You could even use a wire and let it touch ground when you want a "press". That also would work correctly. The only requirement is, that the part has to make a direct connection between the digital input pin and ground when pressed and it has to release that connection when no longer pressed.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you had that experience with that other group. Sometimes people forget that they are there to help people who ask questions, not tell them [how stupid the question is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_such_thing_as_a_stupid_question).

Comment: I am very cautious when it comes to electricity, so I need to ask a lot of things and make sure nothing bad will happen. But a lot of users in technical user groups seem to view beginners as cannon fodder and use them to show off and boast their ego. The question will not be answered, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect them with no external pull up resistors. If those switch wires are more than a few inches long or you are in an electrical noisy environment I would suggest an external pull up as well as the wires will act as an antenna. The internal pull ups are week so electrical noise can easily overpower them. The buttons you selected will probably oxidize over time and fail as the oxide is an insulator. To prevent that use pull up resistors that will force at least 1mA through the contacts (old school). We use to be sure we had some current through the switch when it was not a dry contact switch (those were expensive). Rule of thumb was at least 1mA more was good. This also helped reduce noise in the switch lines. Long term this is much more effective then sealing the switch.

Comment: Thanks for this information. What can be done to prevend oxidizing? Will hot glue on the back be a good idea once the soldering is done?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetting_current